# Get value from textbox

Tags: php

I want to get the value of a textbox in PHP, and when I try this:

```
<form method=post action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="Hex" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />  
</form>
```

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['Hex'];
echo $test;
?>
```

I just get the error:

> Undefined index: Hex

I've Googled to no avail; so please someone, help me!

Comment: Does your php code reside in the same file as the HTML code, or is that PHP code inside `update.php`?

Comment: do var_dump($_POST); in your php

Comment: @Michael It is in the update.php file.

Comment: @heximal Still getting the same error

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` before `$test = ..`. Also, your form 'method' does not have 'brackets' ("post" instead of post).

Comment: Yeah, noticed that(or it? bad english:/) :) THanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think the issue is with the **quotation marks**, @GuiceU you forgot to add the quotes  to post.

Just replace your **method = post** with **method="post"**

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="Hex" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />  
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
               $test = $_POST['Hex'];
               echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope this help you:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$test = $_POST['Hex'];
echo $test;
} else { ?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="Hex" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" />  
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Still, you can try this:

Make your form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
```

and try to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Don't use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` if you don't have to. Security reasons.

Comment: @nauphal, then we try to figure out **why** it doesn't work, not expose the OP to unnecessary vulnerabilities.

Comment: i think the issue with quotation marks, @GuiceU forget to add the quotes before and after post, method="post"

Answer (score 0):

Use at the start of the script

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```